# How to give a dynamic path in the image upload function?

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

I am trying to upload images into its respective folders using PHP. There are totally 6 folders and 2 folders have subfolders. I have created a dropdown containing a list of folders and subfolders in a form. Now I am able to create thumbnails but not able to store original images in respective folders. How can I write a dynamic path in the function?

I want to use below dynamic path:

```
$target_folder = "images/website/". $_POST["path"]."/";
```

But I get error for the this path.

Below is the following code for cwUpload function.

```
  <?php
function cwUpload($field_name = '', $target_folder = '', $file_name = '', $thumb = FALSE, $thumb_folder = '', $thumb_width = '', $thumb_height = ''){
//folder path setup
$target_path = $target_folder;
$thumb_path = $thumb_folder;

//file name setup
$filename_err = explode(".",$_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
$filename_err_count = count($filename_err);
$file_ext = $filename_err[$filename_err_count-1];
if($file_name != '')
{
    $fileName = $file_name.'.'.$file_ext;
}
else
{
    $fileName = $_FILES[$field_name]['name'];
}

//upload image path
$upload_image = $target_path.basename($fileName);

//upload image
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name'],$upload_image))
{
    //thumbnail creation
    if($thumb == TRUE)
    {
        $thumbnail = $thumb_path.$fileName;
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
        $thumb_create = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);
        switch($file_ext){
            case 'jpg':
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                break;
            case 'jpeg':
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $source = imagecreatefrompng($upload_image);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $source = imagecreatefromgif($upload_image);
                break;
            default:
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
        }
        imagecopyresized($thumb_create,$source,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);
        switch($file_ext){
            case 'jpg' || 'jpeg':
                imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                break;
            case 'png':
                imagepng($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                imagegif($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                break;
            default:
                imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
        }
    }

    return $fileName;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
  if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])){

//call thumbnail creation function and store thumbnail name
$upload_img = cwUpload('fileToUpload','images/','',TRUE,'images/thumbs/','200','160');

//full path of the thumbnail image
$thumb_src = 'images/thumbs/'.$upload_img;

//set success and error messages
$message = $upload_img?"<span style='color:#008000;'>Image thumbnail have been created successfully.</span>":"<span style='color:#F00000;'>Some error occurred, please try again.</span>";

    }else{    
    `//if form is not submitted, below variable should be blank
     $thumb_src = '';
      $message = '';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: please check the permission of the corresponding folder

Comment: please add some sensible code indentation

Comment: @Elby I have checked the permission. I can add images when I try to upload images directly without creating thumbnails. I just need a correct path in the $target_folder part

Comment: automatically create folder and sub folder

Comment: It already has a set of folder and subfolders

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dynamic directory's to do that. 
Just create a target folder before a 
    **move_uploaded_file**

```
mkdir("images/website/'. $_POST[path].'");
$target_folder = "images/website/". $_POST['path']."/";
```

Comment: Asusual thumbnail is created but i am getting this error  Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in